# How to determine which languages have been loaded by babel or polyglossia?

Tags: babel, polyglossia

I am trying to find a way of determining, say at the end of the preamble, which languages have been loaded by babel and polyglossia, including the main language and all others. There are ways to detect if a particular language has been loaded but I need a way to enumerate all languages which have been loaded. Any ideas by people who know the internals to these packages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With babel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter Loaded languages: \bbl@loaded
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't see any code in polyglossia which would give such a list, so one would probably have to patch polyglossia, or you could make a feature request.

### Addition

I now tested also some variants. Modifiers seems to be ignored in the list (this probably what you would want), and the main language is the first language in the list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin.medieval,english,main=ngerman,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter Loaded languages: \bbl@loaded
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've opened a feature request - it's not obvious how to patch because it depends on load order.

Comment: I also submitted a patch for polyglossia to add `bbl@loaded`.

Comment: The patch has been merged and so this change should be in the next polyglossia release and `bbl@loaded` should be possible for both babel and polyglossia.

Comment: The patch changed to make it `xpg@loaded` to bring it in line with the polyglossia internal macro prefix.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote the [`tracklang`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang) package to help my packages work out this kind information.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[british,canadien]{babel}
\usepackage{tracklang}

\begin{document}

\AnyTrackedLanguages
{Root Languages.

\ForEachTrackedLanguage{\thislang}{Language: \thislang. }

Dialects.

\ForEachTrackedDialect{\thisdialect}{Dialect: \thisdialect. }
}
{No language options detected.}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of language and dialect lists]

This also works with `translator`:

```
\documentclass[british,canadien]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{tracklang}

\begin{document}

\AnyTrackedLanguages
{Root Languages.

\ForEachTrackedLanguage{\thislang}{Language: \thislang. }

Dialects.

\ForEachTrackedDialect{\thisdialect}{Dialect: \thisdialect. }
}
{No language options detected.}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: image of language and dialect lists]

Or with no language package at all, but recognised language names in the document class (or `tracklang`) option list:

```
\documentclass[british,canadien]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tracklang}

\begin{document}

\AnyTrackedLanguages
{Root Languages.

\ForEachTrackedLanguage{\thislang}{Language: \thislang. }

Dialects.

\ForEachTrackedDialect{\thisdialect}{Dialect: \thisdialect. }
}
{No language options detected.}

\end{document}
```

This produces the same as the previous example.

Also works with `ngerman`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{tracklang}

\begin{document}

\AnyTrackedLanguages
{Root Languages.

\ForEachTrackedLanguage{\thislang}{Language: \thislang. }

Dialects.

\ForEachTrackedDialect{\thisdialect}{Dialect: \thisdialect. }
}
{No language options detected.}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: image of language and dialect]

Unfortunately, `polyglossia` doesn't provide a convenient way of accessing the dialect option, so only the root language can be detected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}

\usepackage{tracklang}

\begin{document}

\AnyTrackedLanguages
{Root Languages.

\ForEachTrackedLanguage{\thislang}{Language: \thislang. }

Dialects.

\ForEachTrackedDialect{\thisdialect}{Dialect: \thisdialect. }
}
{No language options detected.}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: image of language and dialect, both just english]

Comment: This is interesting - I hope polyglossia adds some simple macro like `bbl@loaded` because I would rather not rely on another package if I can help it.

Comment: @PLK Yes, it's quite frustrating for package authors who need to provide support for `polyglossia` users. The `tracklang` package checks `\bbl@loaded` if it's been defined, but for `polyglossia` it has to iterate through all the language names `polyglossia` supports and checks if `\ `⟨lang⟩`@loaded` exists, which is messy and doesn't take into account any new languages that may later be added to `polyglossia`. This was the main reason for writing `tracklang` so that I didn't have to include that mess in every package I write.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of doing ... it would be trivial for polyglossia to add `bbl@loaded`.

Comment: I submitted a patch to add `bbl@loaded` to polyglossia. I think it's fairly trivial.